# Assert super type as a generic parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### The Question

In TypeScript we can use `extends` to assert a generic parameter as a 'subtype' of another type. E.g.

```
// class Base {}
// class Child extends Base {}
// edited:
class Base { a = 1 }
class Child extends Base { b = 2 } // Child is a sub class of Base

class Test {
  // assert T is a subtype of Base
  hello<T extends Base>() { ... }
}

new Test().hello<Child>();
```

But how to assert a generic parameter to be a 'supertype' of another type? E.g.

```
class Test2 {
  // HERE, how to ensure T is a super type of Child
  hello<T ??? Child>() { ... }
}

new Test2().hello<Base>();
```

### Use Case

```
// class Actions<T = unknown> {
// edited:
class Actions<T = never> {
  execs: (() => T)[]

  append(exec: () => T) {
    this.execs.push(exec)
    return this;
  }

  // HERE, how to ensure NewT is a super type of T?
  setT<NewT ??? T>() {
    return this as Actions<NewT>;
  }
}

// to make the following work
new Actions()
  .setT<Child>()
  .append(() => new Child())
  // before this line, all exec should return Child
  // after this line, all exec should return Base
  .setT<Base>()
  .append(() => new Base())
  .execs.map(e => e()) // => Base[]
```

If we still use `extends` like this:

```
setT<NewT extends T>() {
  return this as Actions<NewT>;
}
```

Got error:

```
Conversion of type 'this' to type 'Actions<NewT>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Actions<T>' is not comparable to type 'Actions<NewT>'.
    Type 'T' is not comparable to type 'NewT'.
      'NewT' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.ts(2352)
```

Yes I can use `unknown` to transform the return type, but the signature of the function `setT` couldn't express the type constraint we want.

Comment: There are few problems with your examples that you might want to [edit]; first, please add members to your `Child` and `Base` classes so they are not structurally identical, as that makes for bad examples (currently `Base extends Child` is true, for example).  Second, please choose a universal subtype default for `new Actions()` if you want `new Actions().setT<Child>()` to be possible; you've got it defaulting to `unknown`, but `unknown extends Child` is false so I'm not sure what you're trying to do; presumably you want `new Actions<SomeSubtypeOfChild>.setT<Child>`.

Comment: (see prev comment) Once you fix those: There is no built-in lower bound constraint in TS (see [ms/TS#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520)) but you can write an implementation which emulates it for some use cases; see [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKrBMm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the comments. I've edited the question regarding to your first point. About your second point, the chained call `new Actions<unknown>().setT<Child>().setT<Base>()` should narrow down the generic type from `unknown` to `Child` to `Base`, so I set `T` defaults to `unknown` that `Child extends unknown` is true.

Comment: @jcalz besides, thanks for the links and demo you provided. Currently I'm using your approach as a workaround. A native support by the TypeScript language would be better to remove that conditional constraint and `any` type casting, but the workaround is intuitive enough for me. Please write an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @jcalz My fault. Your second point is right, `T` should defaults to `never` instead of `unknown`. I've edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no direct way in TypeScript to specify a *lower bound* [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Right now we only have *upper bound* constraints of the form `T extends U` which enforce that `T` must be a subtype of `U`. There's no analogous constraints of the form `T super U` which would enforce that `T` must be a supertype of `U`.  There is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520), and if you want to this implemented you might want to add a  to that issue.  For now, though, it's not part of the language, and you need to work around it.

One possible workaround is to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in the constraint, of the form `T extends (U extends T ? unknown : never)`.  It's weird-looking, but `U extends T` is the constraint you'd really like to enforce, and so the conditional type `U extends T ? unknown : never` will evaluate to `unknown` if the constraint is met, and `never` if it is not.  So `T extends (U extends T ? unknown : never)` will succeed if `T super U` would succeed (since all types extend `unknown`) and will fail if `T super U` would fail, mostly (no type except `never` extends `never`, so if `T` is not `never` then this behaves as desired... but if `T` is `never` there's no way to prevent it from being accepted.  It's a workaround, so ‍♂️).

For your `Base`/`Child`, that looks like

```
class Base { a = 1 }
class Child extends Base { b = 2 }
class Grandchild extends Child { c = 3 }
class Test2 {
  hello<T extends Child extends T ? unknown : never>() { }
}

new Test2().hello<Base>(); // okay
new Test2().hello<Grandchild>(); // error
```

Notice that you are allowed to specify a supertype but not a subtype.  Then for `Actions` you get

```
class Actions<T = never> {
  execs: (() => T)[] = []

  append(exec: () => T) {
    this.execs.push(exec)
    return this;
  }

  setT<NewT extends ([T] extends [NewT] ? unknown : never)>() {
    return this as any as Actions<NewT>;
  }
}
```

This is similar except since `T` is a type parameter, I had to wrap the `T extends NewT` to `[T] extends [NewT]` to avoid making it a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  And now the following works:

```
new Actions()
  .setT<Child>()
  .append(() => new Child())
  .setT<Base>()
  .append(() => new Base())
  .execs.map(e => e()) // => Base[]
```

Looks good.  Ideally someday there will be a true lower bound constraint and we can abandon the workarounds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#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)